# jquery- How to Call public method of jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a drag and drop plugin . [fieldChooser](https://github.com/mateagar/fieldChooser)

I want to call a method and an event But I don't know how . 
this is the function :

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.fieldChooser = function (sourceList, destinationList, options)
    {
    var fieldChooser = this;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Poor man's singleton 
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (this.getOptions)
    {
        return this;
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private methods 
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    function getBounds(element)
    {
        var offset = element.offset();
        return {
            left: offset.left,
            right: offset.left + element.width(),
            top: offset.top,
            bottom: offset.top + element.height()
        }
    }

    function translateBounds(bounds, newPosition)
    {
        return {
            left: newPosition.left,
            right: bounds.right + newPosition.left - bounds.left,
            top: newPosition.top,
            bottom: bounds.bottom + newPosition.top - bounds.top
        }
    }

    function hitTest(container, element, newPosition)
    {
        var containerBounds = getBounds(container);
        var elementBounds = getBounds(element);
        elementBounds = translateBounds(elementBounds, newPosition);

        var hit = true;
        if (elementBounds.right < containerBounds.left)
        {
            hit = false;
        }
        else if (elementBounds.left > containerBounds.right)
        {
            hit = false;
        }
        else if (elementBounds.bottom < containerBounds.top)
        {
            hit = false;
        }
        else if (elementBounds.top > containerBounds.bottom)
        {
            hit = false;
        }
        return hit;
    }

    var _chooser = this;
    var _lastSelectionList = null;
    function onListSelectionChanged(event, list)
    {
        if (_lastSelectionList)
        {
            if (_lastSelectionList == list)
            {
                // continue
            }
            else
            {
                var otherList = _chooser.getSourceList();
                if (list == _chooser.getSourceList())
                {
                    otherList = _chooser.getDestinationList();
                }
                otherList.clearSelection(true);
            }
        }
        _lastSelectionList = list;
    }


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // fieldList class 
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    var fieldList = function (parent, tabIndex)
    {
        var _list = $(parent);
        _list.addClass("fc-field-list");
        _list.attr("tabIndex", tabIndex);

        var _selectedIndex = -1;
        var _extendedSelectionIndex = -1;

        var prepareListFields = function (content)
        {
            content.addClass("fc-field");
            content.attr("tabIndex", tabIndex);

            content.off("click.field");
            content.on("click.field", function (event)
            {
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();

                var $this = $(this);
                var currentList = _chooser.getFieldList($this);
                if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey)
                {
                    currentList.toggleFieldSelection($this);
                }
                else if (event.shiftKey)
                {
                    currentList.selectTo($this);
                }
                else
                {
                    currentList.selectField($this);
                }
                _currentList = currentList;
            });
        };

        prepareListFields(_list.children());

        _list.selectAt = function (index)
        {
            this.clearSelection(true);
            var fields = _list.getFields();
            if (index >= fields.length)
            {
                index = fields.length - 1;
            }

            var selectedField = null;
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                selectedField = fields.eq(index);
            }

            if (selectedField)
            {
                selectedField.addClass("fc-selected");
                _selectedIndex = index;
                _list.scrollToField(selectedField);
            }
            else
            {
                _selectedIndex = -1;
            }
            _list.trigger("selectionChanged", [_list]);
        }

        _list.extendSelection = function (up)
        {
            var selectedIndex = this.getSelectedIndex();
            var extendedIndex = this.getExtendedSelectionIndex();
            var newIndex = extendedIndex;
            var extend = true;
            if (up)
            {
                if (newIndex < 0)
                {
                    newIndex = _list.getFields().length;
                    _selectedIndex = newIndex - 1;
                }

                if (extendedIndex > selectedIndex)
                {
                    extend = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    newIndex--;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (newIndex < 0)
                {
                    _selectedIndex = 0;
                }

                if (extendedIndex < selectedIndex)
                {
                    extend = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    newIndex++;
                }
            }

            var fields = _list.getFields();
            if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= fields.length)
            {
                // continue
            }
            else
            {
                var selectedField = fields.eq(newIndex);
                if (extend)
                {
                    selectedField.addClass("fc-selected");
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedField.removeClass("fc-selected");
                    if (up)
                    {
                        newIndex--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newIndex++;
                    }

                    if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < fields.length)
                    {
                        selectedField = fields.eq(newIndex);
                    }
                }

                _list.scrollToField(selectedField);

                _list.trigger("selectionChanged", [_list]);
                _extendedSelectionIndex = newIndex;
            }
        }

        _list.selectField = function (field)
        {
            this.clearSelection(true);
            field.addClass("fc-selected");
            _selectedIndex = field.index();
            _list.trigger("selectionChanged", [_list]);
        }

        _list.toggleFieldSelection = function (field)
        {
            field.toggleClass("fc-selected");
            if (field.hasClass("fc-selected"))
            {
                _selectedIndex = field.index();
                _extendedSelectionIndex = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_selectedIndex == field.index())
                {
                    _selectedIndex = _list.children(".fc-selected").first().index();
                }
            }
            _list.trigger("selectionChanged", [_list]);
        }

        _list.selectTo = function (fieldOrIndex)
        {
            var fieldIndex = fieldOrIndex;
            if (typeof fieldOrIndex == "object")
            {
                fieldIndex = fieldOrIndex.index();
            }

            if (_selectedIndex == -1)
            {
                _selectedIndex = 0;
            }

            var children = _list.children();
            if (fieldIndex > _selectedIndex)
            {
                for (var counter = _selectedIndex;
                     counter < children.length;
                     counter++)
                {
                    if (counter <= fieldIndex)
                    {
                        children.eq(counter).addClass("fc-selected");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        children.eq(counter).removeClass("fc-selected");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (var counter = _selectedIndex;
                     counter >= 0;
                     counter--)
                {
                    if (counter >= fieldIndex)
                    {
                        children.eq(counter).addClass("fc-selected");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        children.eq(counter).removeClass("fc_selected");
                    }
                }
            }

            _extendedSelectionIndex = fieldIndex;

            _list.trigger("selectionChanged", [_list]);
        }

        _list.getSelectedIndex = function ()
        {
            return _selectedIndex;
        }

        _list.getExtendedSelectionIndex = function ()
        {
            var index = _extendedSelectionIndex;
            if (index < 0)
            {
                index = _selectedIndex;
            }
            return index;
        }

        _list.getSelection = function ()
        {
            return this.children(".fc-selected");
        }

        _list.clearSelection = function (suppressEvent)
        {
            _selectedIndex = -1;
            _extendedSelectionIndex = -1;
            this.children().removeClass("fc-selected");
            if (suppressEvent)
            {
                // continue
            }
            else
            {
                _list.trigger("selectionChanged", [_list]);
            }
        };

        _list.add = function (content)
        {
            prepareListFields(content);
            content.appendTo(_list);
            return _list;
        };

        _list.getFields = function ()
        {
            return _list.children();
        }

        _list.scrollToField = function (field)
        {
            var listTop = _list.position().top;
            var listScrollTop = _list.scrollTop();
            var listHeight = _list.height();
            var listScrollBottom = listScrollTop + listHeight;

            var fieldHeight = field.outerHeight();
            var fieldTop = listScrollTop + field.position().top - listTop;
            var fieldBottom = fieldTop + fieldHeight;

            if (fieldTop < listScrollTop)
            {
                _list.scrollTop(fieldTop);
            }
            else if (fieldBottom > listScrollBottom)
            {
                _list.scrollTop(listScrollTop + (fieldBottom - listScrollBottom));
            }
        };

        _list.sortable({
            connectWith: ".fc-field-list",
            cursor: "move",
            opacity: 0.75,
            cursorAt: { left: 5, top: 5 },
            helper: function (event, field)
            {
                if (field.hasClass("fc-selected"))
                {
                    // continue
                }
                else
                {
                    _list.selectField(field);
                }

                var helper = fieldChooser.getOptions().helper(_list);
                var selection = _list.getSelection().clone();
                if (helper)
                {
                    // continue
                }
                else
                {
                    helper = $("<div/>").append(selection);
                }

                field.data("selection", selection);
                field.siblings(".fc-selected").remove();

                return helper;
            }
        });

        return _list;
    };

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private variables 
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    var _options = $.extend({}, $.fn.fieldChooser.defaults, options);
    var tabIndex = parseInt(this.attr("tabIndex"));
    if (isNaN(tabIndex))
    {
        tabIndex = 0;
    }
    this.removeAttr("tabIndex");
    var _sourceList = new fieldList(sourceList, tabIndex).addClass("fc-source-fields");
    var _destinationList =
        new fieldList(destinationList, tabIndex).addClass("fc-destination-fields");
    var _currentList = null;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Public properties 
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    this.getOptions = function ()
    {
        return _options;
    };

    this.getSourceList = function ()
    {
        return _sourceList;
    };

    this.getDestinationList = function ()
    {
        return _destinationList;
    };

    this.getFieldList = function (field)
    {
        var list = _destinationList;
        if (field.parent().hasClass("fc-source-fields"))
        {
            list = _sourceList;
        }
        return list;
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Public methods
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    this.destroy = function ()
    {
        this.getOptions = null;
        _sourceList.sortable("destroy");
        _destinationList.sortable("destroy");
    };

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Event handlers 
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    _destinationList.on("sortstop", function (event, ui)
    {
        var selection = ui.item.data("selection");

        if (hitTest(_sourceList, ui.item, ui.offset))
        {
            _currentList = _sourceList;
            _sourceList.add(selection);
            _destinationList.clearSelection();
            _sourceList.trigger("selectionChanged", [_sourceList]);
            _chooser.trigger("listChanged", [selection, _sourceList]);
            ui.item.after(selection).remove();
        }
        else if (hitTest(_destinationList, ui.item, ui.offset))
        {
            ui.item.after(selection).remove();
        }
        else
        {
            _destinationList.getSelection().remove();
            _sourceList.add(selection);
            _sourceList.scrollToField(selection);
            _destinationList.clearSelection();
            _sourceList.trigger("selectionChanged", [_sourceList]);
            _currentList = _sourceList;
            _chooser.trigger("listChanged", [selection, _sourceList]);
        }
    });

    _sourceList.on("sortstop", function (event, ui)
    {
        var selection = ui.item.data("selection");

        if (hitTest(_destinationList, ui.item, ui.offset))
        {
            _currentList = _destinationList;
            _destinationList.add(selection);
            _sourceList.clearSelection();
            _destinationList.trigger("selectionChanged", [_destinationList]);
            _chooser.trigger("listChanged", [selection, _destinationList]);
        }
        else if (hitTest(_sourceList, ui.item, ui.offset))
        {
            // continue
        }
        else
        {
            _sourceList.sortable("cancel");
        }

        ui.item.after(selection).remove();
    });

    _destinationList.on("selectionChanged", onListSelectionChanged);
    _sourceList.on("selectionChanged", onListSelectionChanged);

    _destinationList.on("focusin", function ()
    {
        _currentList = _destinationList;
    });

    _destinationList.on("focusout", function ()
    {
        if (_currentList == _destinationList)
        {
            _currentList = null;
        }
    });

    _sourceList.on("focusin", function ()
    {
        _currentList = _sourceList;
    });

    _sourceList.on("focusout", function ()
    {
        if (_currentList == _sourceList)
        {
            _currentList = null;
        }
    });

    $(document).keydown(function (event)
    {
        if (_currentList)
        {
            if (event.which == 38)
            { // up arrow
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                if (event.shiftKey)
                {
                    _currentList.extendSelection(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    var selectedIndex = _currentList.getSelectedIndex();
                    var newIndex = selectedIndex - 1;
                    if (newIndex < 0)
                    {
                        newIndex = 0;
                    }
                    _currentList.selectAt(newIndex);
                }
            }
            else if (event.which == 40)
            { // down arrow 
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                if (event.shiftKey)
                {
                    _currentList.extendSelection(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    var selectedIndex = _currentList.getSelectedIndex();
                    var newIndex = selectedIndex + 1;
                    if (selectedIndex < 0)
                    {
                        newIndex = _currentList.getFields().length - 1;
                    }
                    _currentList.selectAt(newIndex);
                }
            }
            else if (event.which == 27)
            { // escape
                _currentList.selectAt(-1);
            }
        }
    });

    return this;
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Class defaults
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$.fn.fieldChooser.defaults = {
    helper: function (list) { return null; }
};

}(jQuery));
```

I want just 2-3 functions and I don't need other ones .

I want to call getDestinationList() to get the fields inside destinationlist and call selectionChanged() event.

Could you help me ? How can I call them ?

these are the definition codes :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var $sourceFields = $("#sourceFields");
            var $destinationFields = $("#destinationFields");
            var $chooser = $("#fieldChooser").fieldChooser(sourceFields, destinationFields);

        });
```

I'm looking forward to hear from you

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't forked the project and added custom code tot he project to be able to call these methods from your own version?

Comment: I haven't added any code to this plugin , I need to call the pre defined methods and events

Comment: You would need to change the source of the plugin to accomplish this or do some monkey patching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$chooser.on("listChanged",function(event,selection,list){
    //event <- The jQuery event invoking the callback.
    //selection <- The field (or set of fields) which has moved.
    //list <- The field list to which the selection has moved.
    alert("listChanged");

}
```

Documentation link: https://github.com/mateagar/fieldChooser

I hope this help.